# Prometheus scrape agent not finding spring boot 3 service

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Migrated a service from spring boot 2 to 3. I see metrics being exposed under /actuator/Prometheus end point. However Prometheus agent sees this k8s service pod as down. And hence we don't see metrics being processed by scrape agent. Could anyone help us figure out what is missing here. It works fine if we switch back to spring boot 2.

I can do wget from scrape agent on the /actuator/Prometheus and see metrics.